# ruby-grape - requires method not working 3 levels deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, grape-api

I am building an API right now using Grape and Rails. One endpoint takes POST requests for Orders. The architecture is as follows:
An `Order has_many OrderDetails`. `OrderDetails has_many OrderDetailCustomFields`.

As such, I would expect that POST request JSON objects will have values nested three levels deep. 
My code looks as follows for my orders endpoint:
*(bare in mind I have gotten rid of most of the other fields, so those who help me can look at just the nesting of parameter requirements)*

```
params do 
    requires :order, :type => Hash do
        requires :order_details, :type => Array do
            requires :order_detail, :type => Hash do
                requires :cost, type: Integer#, desc:
                requires :quantity_ordered, type: Integer#, desc:
                requires :item_id, type: Integer#, desc:
                optional :order_detail_custom_fields, :type => Array do
                    optional :order_detail_custom_field, :type => Hash do
                        requires :field_name, type: String#, desc:
                        optional :field_value, type: String#, desc:
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I have other endpoints that have optional arrays and optional hashes. If nested fields in those optional arrays or hashes are **required**, Grape will typically ONLY throw an error if the parent parameter exists in the request.

However in the case of `:order_detail_custom_field` that is not the case. As soon as I go from from 2 parameter levels deep to 3 parameter levels deep, Grape barks at me and seems to make the entire `:order_detail_custom_field` Array required for all `:order_details` Hashes. Even though it is optional. Other `:order_detail` hashes that do not have custom_fields now get errors stating that they require `:field_name` for `:order_detail_custom_field`.

The exact error is:

```
  {
error:  order[order_details][order_detail][order_detail_custom_fields][order_detail_custom_field][field_name] is missing
}
```

The only difference I can see is that the errors seem to be happening to parameters that are 3 levels deep rather than 2 levels deep. Does anyone have experience with this? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this question, I have submitted a github issue which has been marked as "bug?" . I will update as I have more information.

Comment: This issue is Still happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, I have submitted a github issue which has been marked as "bug?". As far as I know this issue is still happening as per @JGonzalesD.